# Shell script to write and read data from serial communication

Tags: linux, shell

I am making a simple shell script to write and read data to serial device.
I am using these commands at terminal and they are responding correctly:

To write I am using:

```
echo -en '\xAA\x04\xC2' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

To read I am using read:

```
cat -v < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

but when I am including this in a shell script, it is not responding. I need help regarding this.
Also I want to know that when I send the write command, It should give me output in hex format but it is giving me output in this format M--*^NM-^H
Also need help in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect that your `cat` statement is blocking waiting for end-of-file. It may treat your input tty as a standard terminal device, in which case it will require an end-of-file character to terminate the input (e.g, Control-D) and it could apply other processing to the input and the output. You had best familiarize yourself with the `stty` command and its options (see [stty man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stty)). Try doing `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0` to see what options are set.

The easiest way of reading the input might be to read a single character at a time. You could try with the following script. This will read a single character at a time from the input until a 'q' is entered.

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -echo
while read -rs -n 1 c && [[ $c != 'q' ]]
do
        echo "read <$c>" # Replace this with code to handle the characters read
done < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

If -F does not work, redirect stdin to the device.

For your output problem, I think it is working but you are seeing the characters displayed as characters and not the hex-codes. To see the hex codes (for verification testing only - I don't think you want to send the hex codes to the terminal), try:

```
echo -en '\xAA\x04\xC2' | od -tx1
```

You may also want to have raw mode set when outputting to avoid the driver changing the output characters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried your suggestion of od -tx1 but it is not giving me any response. I am sending: echo -en '\xAA\x04\xC2' | od -tx1 > /dev/ttyUSB0. Can you tell me the complete command to send. Thanks

Comment: The code which you have given me is giving error:
stty: invalid argument `-F'

Comment: Try redirecting from stdin instead

Comment: Can you provide me the code pls. I want to send 0xAA,0x04,0xC2,0x90 and output I will get is : 0xAD. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: The code which you have given me is giving output like this: read <�>
when I have tested the same command in terminal, I get "M--" which you said is ascii(I can deal with M--), but now what is this "read <�>". Please help in decoding this.
Is there a way in which I can check that my hex values has been sent to serial device properly.

Comment: My code is just an example: as you can see on line 5 there is an echo statement that outputs "read <$c>" where $c is the character it read. You need to replace that with the code that does what you want to do with the input received. For checking what is sent - the only thing you can do is pipe the output into `od` and see what it says.

Comment: Thanks I have done everything and I am getting the data in hex format but the problem with your example code is that it is responding line by line, for example: 
read <AA> 
read <06> 
read <30> 
I want to store it in array, for example: arry[]= AA,06,30. How to do this?

Comment: I also want to know that how can I check for EOF. I mean when I have received all the input it should move out of the loop. How to do this.?

Comment: Assuming you are using `bash` you can append to an array `a` using `a+=$c` - see this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951506/bash-add-value-to-array-without-specifying-a-key)

Answer (score 0):

I've found another method I'd like to share:

```bash
echo "blabla" > /dev/ttyx & answer=$(head -n1 /dev/ttyx)
```

The `&` puts the transfer from `echo` to the port immediately in the background, while head waits until it gets one line as an answer, which is then put into a variable.