# LARGE_INTEGER and BYTE types in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows

I am studying one Windows code which converting to Linux and this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31111116/54964). 
It is possible that there are no injective datatypes between LARGE_INTEGER and BYTE in Linux so special situations may need to be considered.

The two data types could possibly replaced by the following two in Linux

- uint64_t
- unsigned char

where the first one is a part of `stdint.h`.
I would propose replace both LARGE_INTEGER and BYTE by uint64_t but not certain.

Which Linux datatypes can use in place of LARGE_INTEGER and BYTE?

---

The following file is a case example of National Instruments' driver for MCA 8000A described [here](http://www.amptek.com/mca8000a-multichannel-analyzer-software-downloads/).

MictoTime.h

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// MicroTime.h: interface for the MicroTime class.
//
// This header file is a part of the PMCA COM package
//
// Amptek Inc. 2000
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#if !defined(AFX_MICROTIME_H__495147C7_F0B7_11D1_B62F_9CFF0CC10000__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_MICROTIME_H__495147C7_F0B7_11D1_B62F_9CFF0CC10000__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER >= 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER >= 1000

class MicroTimeType  
{
    LARGE_INTEGER m_startTime;
    double m_microScale;
    BOOL m_waiting;
public:
    MicroTimeType();
    LARGE_INTEGER GetCounter();
    double Get(void);
    double Wait(double microSec);
    void CancelWait(void);
};

#endif // !defined(AFX_MICROTIME_H__495147C7_F0B7_11D1_B62F_9CFF0CC10000__INCLUDED_)
```

Do you need to add here new types of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31129201/54964)?
Do you need to define `uint8_t` anywhere else?

Comment: You need to figure out what bit length and signedness those types have to find equivalents (locate where they are defined). The other two you listed are standard C (may need `<stdint.h>` for the uint64_t).

Comment: `BYTE` is surely `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`. I don't know about `LARGE_INTEGER`, probably `uint32_t` but maybe it's larger or smaller than that. This is a question about Windows, not about Linux! Linux doesn't have nonstandard names for standard types like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see [the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) for data types in C supported by Windows API and toolchain.

[LARGE_INTEGER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx) is actually a union representing signed 64-bit integers which has been historically used in some APIs.  Simple `typedef int64_t LARGE_INTEGER;` won't work as expected.

You will need something like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t LONG;
typedef int64_t LONGLONG;

typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    LONG  HighPart;
  };
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    LONG  HighPart;
  } u;
  LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER, *PLARGE_INTEGER;
```

Comment: The datatype LARGE_INTEGER is declared in the header file MicroType.h. How can change this file to be in accordance to your answer? I added the header to the body of the question.