# redirect serial input from device to file in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, io-redirection

I'm working with a device connected to my PC via serial port.
When i send a command to this device (using putty or minicom) it send me back some output.
I would like to save this output (serial input of my PC) on a local file.
I found this workaround to do this:

-In the first terminal i type:

```
 cat -v /dev/ttyACM0 > filename
```

-In another terminal i type:

```
 echo -ne 'cat "filename"\n\r' > /dev/ttyACM
```

It works, but i'd like to automate the process with a single bash script.

```
./serialDownload.sh filename
```

I tried to put in background the first command before executing the second one but it doesn't work...

```
#!/bin/bash 


SERIAL_PORT="/dev/ttyACM0"
BAUDRATE=9600  

stty raw speed $BAUDRATE
./serialListen.sh $1& (->this put in background the first command)
sleep 2
echo -e 'cat "'$1'"\n\r' > $SERIAL_PORT
```

Thank you in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990702/linux-serial-port-listener-and-interpreter

Comment: ...it doesn't really fix my problem but it gives me some good hints i have to work on..thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `wait` or `sleep 1` at the end of the script?